# Workflow has stopped working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-manager

I have a 2013 workflow that creates a sub-site when a new item is added to a specific list. This was working beautifully until today.
Now, whenever a new item is added to the list, the item is added and then the webpage hangs, seemingly stuck before the workflow is started. There is no error. There is no entry in either the Workflow History or Workflow Tasks list.
No helpful information in the ULS logs or event viewer.

What happened and how can I get it back up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem ended up being caused by a drive running full on the database server. Once the space was increased everything went back to normal.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

We had exact same problem day before, where Workflow stop working and after troubleshooting we found that Workflow Manager service was stopped. Please check the following things to make sure Workflow manager is working fine.

- On Workflow Manager server, run following command in workflow powershell `Get-WFFarmStatus` and `Get-SBFarmStatus` Make sure All services status should be 
  running.
- Check in IIS, if AppPool of workflow Manager Site is stopped or IIS site itself stopped.
- check the event log on the Workflow Manager Server.
- Open the Workflow URI in the browser and make sure it return the correct xml.
- from SharePoint central admin, Manager Services application, click on Workflow Proxy and make sure its status say connected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that's not my issue.
All services are running, Apppool is good and WF proxy is connected.

Comment: another thing, you can try, create a new test list and test a brand new workflow 2013....this will prove the if the problem with single workflow or other? also enable verbose logging, may give you the issue

Answer (score 0):

If issue only happened when adding new item , you can try to delete the issued workflow and re-create a new one or test in other list or library .

You can also [clear SharePoint configuration cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Clear-SPDistributedCacheItem?view=sharepoint-ps)

When the page hanging , check the RAM and CPU resource in Task Manager .

Answer (score 0):

> Check the workflow certificate expire date:-

1. Open the workflow website from the IIS.
2. Edit the bindings
3. View SSL certificate.
4. Check the validity TO date.